# How to get SQL Server to read from files?

Tags: sql-server, csv, import, permissions

As the title suggest, I am trying to read a csv file and import it to my table in my database. I get this error message:

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5 (Access is denied)

I tried giving IO permissions in SQL Server Configuration Manager, but it didn't work. I also ran SQL Server as an administrator as well.

Here the code snippet:

```
BULK INSERT EMPLOYEE
FROM 'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio'
WITH
    (FIRSTROW 2,
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    );
```

Comment: You need to give it a filename, not a directory.

Comment: What Corion said. Also if you use your company PC some folders can not be accessed even with administrator. So try putting the CSV somewhere like the desktop if there is such kind of a problem

Comment: Yeah I realize my stupid mistake, thanks!

Comment: @AntoniosKatopodis "put it on the desktop" - err.. that's still inside the users folder. Try putting it in c:\temp instead